# How can i make pointer to a template function?

Tags: c++

I have a template sort function that takes pointer to another function as a paramater to define sorting rule.

```
template<typename T>
void sort(T* arr, int size, function<bool(T, T)>& comparer);
```

and i want to call this function with lambda expression

```
sort(arr, size, [](int num1, int num2) { if (num1 > num2) { return true; } else { return false; } });
```

However i had an error:

> Error (active) E0304   no instance of overloaded function "sort" matches the argument list

Is there a way to create pointer to template function? How can i do this?

Comment: Please clarify: 1. Can you change the signature of `sort`? 2. What do you mean with "*Is there a way to create pointer to template function?*"? There are no function pointers involved in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Template argument deduction will try to deduce `T` from both the first parameter `T* arr` and the third one `function<bool(T, T)>& comparer`.

This will fail, because the lambda doesn't actually have type `function<bool(T, T)>` for any `T`. (It can only be *converted* to one.)

In function templates function objects are usually taken directly by a template parameter, not as `std::function`:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
void sort(T* arr, int size, F comparer);
```

or

```
template<typename T, typename F>
void sort(T* arr, int size, F&& comparer);
```

depending on whether you want a copy of the function object or just a reference.

Comment: It is possible that the signature of `sort` is fixed and OP can't alter it.

Comment: @Ayxan Possible, but didn't understand clearly from OP that this is the case. Changing the function signature is probably preferable, but if OP clarifies otherwise I will edit/remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably want to take a const reference.
2. You have convert to `std::function` explicitly.

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
void sort(T* arr, int size, std::function<bool(T, T)> const & comparer)
{
        // sort
}

int main()
{
    int const size = 10;
    int arr[size];
    sort(arr, size, std::function{[](int num1, int num2) {
        if (num1 > num2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }});
}
```

If you can change the signature of `sort`, see [walnut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60252634/10147399).